# Q&A Mathematica v.11 Neural Networks: A comprehensive look at Layers, Net Functions, and pioneering into this [[experimental]] code

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, guidelines

## Motivation

As Mathematica v.11 was released earlier this month with a host of new `[[experimental]]` functions and a limited number of examples on curated data that do not cover all layers, options, etc., I am posting this with the intent of augmenting Mathematica's documentation via the cumulative knowledge of the coding wizards of Stack Exchange.

#### Why read this?

It includes more details and examples of than the documentation (currently). Also, you will see where there are a lot of peculiarities that may or may not be causing errors in your code. For example, if you are using NetDecoder for classes, it automatically assumes that you are using the UnitVector encoding, there is not a decoder for Booleans, etc.

## Layers

- #### An Overview of *all* NetLayers
- #### `DeconvolutionLayer` Example

## Useful Functions

- #### An Overview of Useful Net Functions (e.g. `NetEncoder`)
- #### Useful User-Defined Functions

## Formatting Input

- #### Troubleshooting Formatting Input

#### Disclaimer

Until this point I have implemented my neural networks in Mathematica by hand. I have a good grasp on the theory behind neural networks (and the associated mathematics); however, Mathematica - being proprietary - does not make it clear as to which algorithms they choose to use to implement their network layers$*$. Therefore I honestly am not sure of the some of these layers' underpinnings.

$*$**Correction from Sebastian** Mathematica uses the same definitions as all the other frameworks. Definitions have become rather standardized, as everyone wants to use the same backends, like cuDNN.

#### Contributors

Both **@Sebastian** and **@JHM** have supplied useful comments and corrections relating to Mathematica code. I have noted where they have been edited in. I also thank **@Sascha** for the clear example on the Deconvolution layer. In addition **@EmilioPisanty** has suggested updating to this new format - which I agree is spiffy - borrowed from **@Mr.Wizard**. **@TaliesinBeynon** has assisted with input formatting. Thank you for helping keep this as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 37):

Thank you for your summary. I would like to clarify and correct a few of your points.

> however, Mathematica - being proprietary - does not make it clear as to which algorithms they choose to use to implement their network layers. Therefore I honestly am not sure of the some of these layers' underpinnings.

We use the same definitions as all the other frameworks. Definitions have become rather standardized, as everyone wants to use the same backends, like cuDNN.

> Because Mathematica designed each Net's nodes / neurons / "ports" to recieve only one input

If you are referring to layers, this is not true: all the loss functions take two inputs.

Regarding `EmbeddingLayer`:

> This to me is odd, as NetEncoder has a specific option for Booleans;

Suppose you are trying to create a vector representation of a very high-dimensional categorical input (like words). NetEncoder will produce one-hot encoded vectors of the same dimension as the number of categories. This can be absolutely massive, and make training impossible. EmbeddingLayer solves this: it maps integers directly to a low-dimensional vector subspace, and this embedding is trained. This allows things like Word2Vec to be implemented (for example). The docs should make this use-case clearer.

Also regarding `EmbeddingLayer`:

> This is the only net layer that I am aware of, that the documentation specifically calls "trainable" for whatever that is worth.

This is not true, see `ConvolutionLayer`, `DotPlusLayer`, etc. "Trainable" just means that it has parameters that can be modified during training.

Regarding `SummationLayer`:

> This really doesn't need any explaination. It is basically the same as Total[]

To be more precise, its more like `Total[array, Infinity]`. `TotalLayer` acts more like `Total[{array1, array2, ...}]`

> Other pecularities are that NetDecoder automatically assumes that your classes are in a UnitVector. Even if you specify "Index" It will produce an error.

This is because your network cannot output an index: no layer allows you to do this. Also, it assumes you are giving the decoder a probability vector for the classes, which allows you to use it like a `ClassifierFunction`.

> Mathematica calls your layers ports. NetPort lets you access them. You can name them...

No, layers are not called ports. The inputs and outputs of layers and containers (like `NetGraph` and `NetChain`) are called "Ports". `NetPort` is a way to unambiguously refer to one of these inputs/outputs. For example, `MeanSquaredLossLayer` has two input ports, "Target" and "Input". Consider:

`NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], DropoutLayer[], 
  MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort[3, "Target"], 
  2 -> NetPort[3, "Input"]}]`

`NetPort` allows you to specify exactly which input/output you are referring to.

> In my mind, I think their implementation of NetGraph is kind of silly. Why? Because if you define a net and then pass it to NetGraph, it doesnt produce a graph;

It does produce a graph, just the net you passed in looks like any other layer (until you click on it and see its structure). The philosophy is that you can use `NetChain` or `NetGraph` objects exactly as you would use normal layers inside other `NetChain` or `NetGraph` objects. It allows for nice definitions of things like Inception networks etc. It also solves namespacing issues elegantly when composing containers.

Answer (score 19):

## Layers

### BatchNormalizationLayer

There are several layers introduced in v.11 that can not be used uninitialized, this is one of them. Input must be either a rank 1 or rank 3 tensor. To be honest, I do not think we can see its true effect on one input as demonstrated by these two examples below. I believe the effect of Batch normalization is only implemented by the function NetTrain. If someone has a simple example of this please let me know and I will update this.

```
batchNet = NetInitialize[BatchNormalizationLayer["Input"->{1}]];

ListLinePlot[Flatten[Table[{i - batchNet[{i}]}, {i, -20, 50}]]]

tensor334 = {{{1, 2, 10, 20}, {3, 4, 30, 40}, {5, 6, 50, 60}}, {{5, 6,
  50, 60}, {7, 8, 70, 80}, {9, 10, 90, 100}}, {{1000, 10000, 1, 
 5}, {500, 5000, 12, 215}, {21312, 325, 6234, 412}}};

batchNet = NetInitialize[BatchNormalizationLayer["Input" -> {3, 3, 4}]];

batchNet[tensor]
```

### CatenateLayer

The `CatenateLayer` is pretty simple. It is the Net akin to `Flatten[]` (if you appended two lists together).  If you aren't exactly impressed by this yet, it has more intresting abilities when it comes to network architecture (see example 2). Because Mathematica designed each Net's nodes / neurons / "ports" to recieve only one input *with the exception  of loss layers that take an association of two rules*, it makes it unintuitive how to project two seperate nodes to a third different node. `CatenateLayer` (and others like it) will allow for this. Running example 2 in your notebook will show how the typically linear `NetGraphs` (in most Mathematica's examples) can become quite more intricate. To demonstrate how intricate it can become (should you have the patience to code it) see example 3.
**Correction above from Sebastian**

> JHM gives a clear distinction about the purposes of the uses of `CatenateLayer` and `FlattenLayer`. See FlattenLayer.

#### Example 1

```
a = {{{1},{2},{3}}};
a//Dimensions
b = CatenateLayer[][a]
b//Dimensions
c = CatenateLayer[][b]
c//Dimensions
```

#### Example 2

```
NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh,TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[],DotPlusLayer[50]}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9}, "Input" -> 2]
```

#### Example 3

```
NetInitialize[
 NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, 
   TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
   DotPlusLayer[50], BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid,
    Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
   DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], DropoutLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
   LogisticSigmoid, BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, 
   Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
   DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
   TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
   DotPlusLayer[50], DotPlusLayer[1]}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 
   2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 
   7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 12 -> 14, 
   11 -> 15, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 12 -> 16, 16 -> 17, 15 -> 17, 
   14 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 18 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 20 -> 21, 19 -> 21, 
   21 -> 22, 23 -> 24, 23 -> 25, 23 -> 26, 24 -> 27, 25 -> 27, 
   24 -> 28, 25 -> 29, 26 -> 28, 26 -> 29, 27 -> 30, 28 -> 30, 
   29 -> 30, 30 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 32 -> 21, 30 -> 33, 8 -> 33, 8 -> 34,
    17 -> 34, 30 -> 35, 17 -> 35, 33 -> 36, 34 -> 36, 34 -> 37, 
   35 -> 37, 37 -> 38, 36 -> 38, 38 -> 39, 39 -> 21, 22 -> 40}, 
  "Input" -> 85]]
```

### CrossEntropyLossLayer

Depending on your familiarity with information theory this layer may or may not make much sense to you. I recommend *Information Theory: a tutorial introduction* if you are new to this concept and want to learn more ([PDF download from the author's ResearchGate account](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261557716_Information_Theory_A_Tutorial_Introduction)).

For a brief and unformal description, Entropy (information) is defined somewhat backwards to most people's intuition e.g. unlike probability where if we are certain of an event occuring we give it the value 1, here if we know something we give it the value 0. Why? Because if we know something happens / will happen, then if that event occurs we do not gain any extra knowledge. So along those lines you can think of Entropy as the surprise or amount of information we gain if something happen.

For example, this gives an output 0

```
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1}, "Target" -> 1|>]
```

And this does not. If we increase the input compared to the target, you can see that the value's magnitude increases.

```
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {2}, "Target" -> 1|>]
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {20}, "Target" -> 1|>]
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {200}, "Target" -> 1|>]

ListLinePlot[Table[{i, CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {i}, "Target" -> 1|>]}, {i, 0,100}]]
```

Here we have been apply our data to the index of the target class. There is also the ability to use the option "Probabilities" to pass your data to a vector of class probabilities.

### ConvolutionLayer

The convolution layer is similar to the padding layer, with the exception of being able to specify the number of outputs.

This layer, unlike others which can either take an arbitrary rank tensor or a rank 1 or rank 3 tesnors, can only take a rank three numerical tensor.

The example below shows how different kernel sizes of {h,w} affect this {3,3,3} tensor input. Here the output channels are limited to 1 for clarity. The first list in this output is the dimensions of the output, followed by the output.

If it seems too confusing, in short, lets say you provide a tensor with dimensions {a,b,c} to ConvolutionLayer[n, {h,w}], the resulting output would be (most likely$*$) a tensor with dimensions {n,b-h+1,c-w+1}. It should be clear that your kernel can't be larger than second and third dimensions of your input tensor.

$*$ we will talk about this formula in the poolying layer.

```
Table[{Dimensions[
NetInitialize[ConvolutionLayer[1, {i, j}, "Input" -> {3, 3, 3}]][
 {
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
  {{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
  {{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
  }
 ]], NetInitialize[
 ConvolutionLayer[1, {i, j}, "Input" -> {3, 3, 3}]][
{
 {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
 {{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
 {{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
 }
]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

### DeconvolutionLayer

It basically "undoes" the `ConvolutionLayer`. However do not be mistaken, if you feed the output of convolution to deconvolution you will not recieved the same result.

```
a={
{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
{{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
{{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
};
a//Dimensions
b=NetInitialize[ConvolutionLayer[1, {1, 1}, "Input" -> {3, 3, 3}]][a];
b//Dimensions
c=NetInitialize[DeconvolutionLayer[3, {1, 1}, "Input" -> {1, 3, 3}]][b];
c//Dimensions
```

### DropoutLayer

This is a pretty important layer (in my opinion), it is similar to a drop out method used my neural network enthusiasts to make neural networks more akin to other ensemble methods like random forest.

In essence it sets it takes one argument, *p*, which is the probability that the its input elements are set to zero during training, and increases the remainder by $\frac{1}{p}$.  This is similar to the `BatchNormalizationLayer` I guess... in the sense that you can not see its effect without training. e.g.
    DropoutLayer[.5][Range[-3, 3]]
Will give you:
    Range[-3, 3]
Unless you are using `NetTrain`. So this makes trying to adapt this for other purposes a bit more tricky. If you know of a way to invoke this without `NetTrain`, please let me know.

### EmbeddingLayer

This is the *one of several* net layers (including `ConvolutionLayer`, `DotPlusLayer`,etc) that I am aware of, that the documentation specifically calls "trainable" (i.e. parameters can be modified during training). It too must be initalized before use. It has two arguments, n and size. It takes integers in [1,n] and puts them into a vector of length size.

```
NetInitialize[EmbeddingLayer[2, 3]][{1}]
NetInitialize[EmbeddingLayer[5, 3]][{1,3,2}]
```

There exists other ways to get this functionality using the other layers. I think this layer really ownly exists because of classes. The documentation gives the following example:

```
NetInitialize[EmbeddingLayer[2, 3, "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Class",{True, False}}]]]
```

This to me is odd, as `NetEncoder` has a specific option for Booleans; However that would not work here as the first argument n, can not be zero (by definition).

**From Sebastian**

> Suppose you are trying to create a vector representation of a very high-dimensional categorical input (like words). `NetEncoder` will produce one-hot encoded vectors of the same dimension as the number of categories. This can be absolutely massive, and make training impossible. `EmbeddingLayer` solves this: it maps integers directly to a low-dimensional vector subspace, and this embedding is trained. This allows things like Word2Vec to be implemented (for example). The docs should make this use-case clearer.

### FlattenLayer

I forgot this in my original post. Thank you JHM for providing this.

```
Catenate[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) *)

CatenateLayer[][{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)

CatenateLayer[][{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}} *)

Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)

FlattenLayer[][{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.} *)

FlattenLayer[][{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]
(* {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.} *)
```

`CatenateLayer` and `FlattenLayer` have different usage. If you want to connect your lists (i.e. flatten only the outermost level), then CatenateLayer would be the correct choice. If you want to make your rank-n tensor into a vector, then FlattenLayer would be appropriate.

Note: `FlattenLayer` automatically converts Integers to Reals. I do not know whether that is intended.

### MeanAbsoluteLossLayer

This layer does exactly what you think it would, tehrefore I am only putting two lines of code which should make it pretty aparent.

```
MeanAbsoluteLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}, "Target" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}|>]

MeanAbsoluteLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}, "Target" -> {1.1, 0.9, 1, 4}|>]
```

If one specifies the Input to be an integer n, e.g.

```
MeanAbsoluteLossLayer["Input"->n];
```

The one can cycle over a tensor where the inner most layer is of length n.

e.g.

```
 MeanAbsoluteLossLayer["Input"->3][<|"Input"->{{1,1,1},{1,.9,1.1}},"Target"->{{1,1,1},{1,1,1}|>];
```

### MeanSquaredLossLayer

Similar to that of above, but, you know, squares first...

```
MeanSquaredLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}, "Target" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}|>]
MeanSquaredLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1, 1, 1, 4}, "Target" -> {1.1, 0.9, 1, 4}|>]
```

### PoolingLayer

This is similar to `ConvolutionLayer`, at least it takes the same inputs, the difference being on the function of the kernel. You can specify the kernel to use the functions `Max`, `Mean` or `Total`. How this works will be clear in the example.

As promised, however, lets talk about the tranformation of a tensor with dimensions {a,b,c} via this function. Foremost, unlike `ConvolutionLayer`, you can not change the output, i.e. the first dimension of the output will always be the same as a Dimension[output] will yield {a,x,y}. So what are the values of x and y? Let us assume you do not mess with the `PaddingSize` or `Stride` options. Then x will be the minimial value of either x-k or x-1, where k is the kernel size {h}. Similarly, y would be the minimum of either y-k or y-1, where kernel size is {w}.

If you want to mess with `PaddingSize` (how many zeros you add to your input) and `Stride` (the step size of your kernel), then the function becomes $Floor[\frac{Min[{x+2p-k+s-1,x+2p-1}]}{s}]$. Same for y.

```
PoolingLayer[{1, 2}][
 {
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
  {{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
  {{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
  }
 ]
PoolingLayer[{2, 2}][
 {
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
  {{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
  {{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
  }
 ]
PoolingLayer[{3, 2}][
 {
  {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 8, 9}},
  {{4, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 3}},
  {{7, 8, 9}, {9, 8, 7}, {4, 5, 6}}
  }
 ]
```

As the default kernel function is `Max`, this output shouldn't be too hard to understand.

### ReshapeLayer

This layer's name says it all. There are some limitations of course. Whatever input you try to reshape needs to be able to fit nicely in that shape. It will not automatically pad or return an untransformed input.

```
ReshapeLayer[{2, 2, 2}][Range[8]]
ReshapeLayer[{1, 8, 1}][Range[8]]
```

### SummationLayer

This really doesn't need any explaination. It is basically the same as `Total[]`, only you should probably specify your input size.

```
 SummationLayer[]
 SummationLayer["Input"->{3}][{1,2,3}]
 Total[{1,2,3}]
```

**From Sebastian**

> To be more precise, its more like `Total[array, Infinity]`. TotalLayer acts more like `Total[{array1, array2, ...}]`

### TotalLayer

This is like list addition. It adds elementwise whatever lists you through at it

```
TotalLayer[][{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}]
{1,2,3} + {1,2,3}
```

Comment: `CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1}, "Target" -> 1|>]` is broken...

Comment: @partida I just ran this, I assure you it is not. Please make sure that the above arrows `->` are reformatted to the Wolfram association arrows

Comment: I checked.`CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1}, "Target" -> 1|>]` throws error `CrossEntropyLossLayer::nfspec: Cannot evaluate net: parameter "TargetForm" is not fully specified.` Version:11.1.0

Comment: @partida I just ran `CrossEntropyLossLayer["Index"][<|"Input"->{2}, "Target"->1|>]` and I was given the result `-0.693147`. Please make sure there are no copy-paste errors (e.g. not Wolfram formatted `|<association braces>|`.  Otherwise please consider opening a new question regarding the error, it may be that in `v11.1.0` some commands have become decrepit

Comment: No writing error. ehh...Ok,I post a new question,maybe the usage have changed.By the way,Thank you for this helpful answer!!!

Comment: I post on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147873/is-the-usage-of-crossentropylosslayer-has-changed.Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for the extensive summary on layers.

There are some points I would like to fix, in addition to @Sebastian 's response.

In `CatenateLayer`

> It is the Net equivalent of Flatten[]

This is close, but not quite correct. The Net equivalent of `Flatten` is `FlattenLayer`.

`CatenateLayer` is derived from the function `Catenate` which connects several lists/vectors/tensors together. The difference between the two layer functions can be seen in the following codes:

`CatenateLayer`:

```
Catenate[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) *)

CatenateLayer[][{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)

CatenateLayer[][{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}} *)
```

`FlattenLayer`:

```
Flatten[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} *)

FlattenLayer[][{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
(* {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.} *)

FlattenLayer[][{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}]
(* {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.} *)
```

`CatenateLayer` and `FlattenLayer` have different usage. If you want to connect your lists (i.e. flatten only the outermost level), then `CatenateLayer` would be the correct choice. If you want to make your rank-n tensor into a vector, then `FlattenLayer` would be appropriate.

Note: `FlattenLayer` automatically converts Integers to Reals. I do not know whether that is intended.

Comment: all nets operate only on floating point values, and always produce them, so it is in fact `CatenateLayer` which is behaving strangely by *not* doing that. It is because layers with a variable number of inputs, such as `CatenateLayer`, cannot participate in 'just-in-time' type inference like the other layers do because their number of inputs is indeterminate. So these layers just use the ordinary mathematica function equivalent when evaluated on their own, which doesn't convert to floating point! This is "inside baseball" stuff.

Comment: Do you note `CatenateLayer[][{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}]===Catenate[{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}]`?

Answer (score 13):

## Useful functions

### NetExtract

This is probably one of the more important functions. I mean, your weights are the nuts and bolts of your network. It has two arguments, net and then layers you want. You can either all them by layer number, or by name.

```
simpleNet = NetChain[<|"Tanh" -> Tanh, "Dot" -> DotPlusLayer[7],"Sigmoid" -> LogisticSigmoid|>, "Input" -> 7];
NetExtract[simpleNet, {"Dot", "Weights"}] // MatrixForm
NetExtract[simpleNet, {"Dot", "Weights"}] // MatrixPlot
```

#### NOTE

You can not get weights of elementwise layers. It will return an error. This means you can not extract all the weights at once. This to me is very stupid (and obnoxious if you use elementwise layers in between your network). It could at least return "Elementwise layer". Anyway, that is just a gripe of mine.

### NetEncoder

`NetEncoder` takes some of the work of preprocessing your data. e.g. if you have used networks before, you are probably used to giving your classes numerical labels.  This just automates that.

```
Print["Scalar", "\t", a = NetEncoder["Scalar"][Range[-3, 3]]];
Print["Class(unitVector)", "\t", 
  b = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"Apple", "Banana"}, 
      "UnitVector"}][{"Apple", "Apple", "Banana"}]];
Print["Class(index)", "\t", 
  c = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"Apple", "Banana"}, "Index"}][{"Apple", 
     "Apple", "Banana"}]];
Print["Boolean", "\t", d = NetEncoder["Boolean"][{True, False, True}]]
```

### NetDecoder

This supposedly undoes the decoder. However there are some, lets say pecularities, of it. Foremoest, there is no `NetDecoder` for `Boolean`. `NetDecoder` for scalar, is also very much like flatten / catenate layers that we have seen before.

```
NetDecoder["Scalar"][{{-3.`}, {-2.`}, {-1.`}, {0.`}, {1.`}, {2.`},{3.`}}]
```

Other pecularities are that `NetDecoder` automatically assumes that your classes are in a `UnitVector`. Even if you specify `"Index"` It will produce an error. Actually, specifying `UnitVector` will cause an error...

```
NetDecoder[{"Class", {"Apple", "Banana"}}][{0, 1}]
NetDecoder[{"Class", {"Apple", "Banana"}, "Index"}][{1}]
NetDecoder[{"Class", {"Apple", "Banana"}, "UnitVector"}][{0, 1}]
```

**From Sebastian**

> This is because your network cannot output an index: no layer allows you to do this. Also, it assumes you are giving the decoder a probability vector for the classes, which allows you to use it like a `ClassifierFunction`

### NetGraph

In my mind, I think their implementation of `NetGraph` is kind of silly. Why? Because if you define a net and then pass it to `NetGraph,` it doesnt produce a graph; however, if you define your net inside `NetGraph` it still functions just like `NetChain`, but you also get the picture and who doesn't love a nice picture?

**From Sebastian**

> It does produce a graph, just the net you passed in looks like any other layer (until you click on it and see its structure). The philosophy is that you can use `NetChain` or `NetGraph` objects exactly as you would use normal layers inside other `NetChain` or `NetGraph` objects. It allows for nice definitions of things like Inception networks etc. It also solves namespacing issues elegantly when composing containers.

The difference in implmenting your network in `NetGraph` rather than `NetChain` is you get a lot more flexibility in defining your network architecture, as you will see in the examples below. Note, if you do not specify the underlying graph structure, it is assumed that your network is linear.

```
tinyNet = NetInitialize[
 NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, 
   TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
   DotPlusLayer[50], DotPlusLayer[1], Tanh}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 
   2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 
   7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 9 -> 10, 10 -> 11}, "Input" -> 3]]

smallNet = 
 NetInitialize[
  NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, 
    TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
    DotPlusLayer[50], BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, 
    LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    CatenateLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], DropoutLayer[],
     TotalLayer[], LogisticSigmoid}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 
    3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 
    8 -> 9, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 12 -> 14, 
    11 -> 15, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 12 -> 16, 16 -> 17, 15 -> 17, 
    14 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 18 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 20 -> 21, 19 -> 21, 
    21 -> 22}, "Input" -> 2122]]

smallishNet = 
 NetInitialize[
  NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, 
    TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
    DotPlusLayer[50], BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, 
    LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    CatenateLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], DropoutLayer[],
     TotalLayer[], LogisticSigmoid, BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, 
    LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    CatenateLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[]}, {1 -> 2, 
    1 -> 3, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 
    5 -> 8, 6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 
    11 -> 14, 12 -> 14, 11 -> 15, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 12 -> 16, 
    16 -> 17, 15 -> 17, 14 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 18 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 
    20 -> 21, 19 -> 21, 21 -> 22, 23 -> 24, 23 -> 25, 23 -> 26, 
    24 -> 27, 25 -> 27, 24 -> 28, 25 -> 29, 26 -> 28, 26 -> 29, 
    27 -> 30, 28 -> 30, 29 -> 30, 30 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 32 -> 21}, 
   "Input" -> 2122]]

smallNotReallyNet = 
 NetInitialize[
  NetGraph[{BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, 
    TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], CatenateLayer[], 
    DotPlusLayer[50], BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, 
    LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    CatenateLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], DropoutLayer[],
     TotalLayer[], LogisticSigmoid, BatchNormalizationLayer[], Tanh, 
    LogisticSigmoid, Tanh, TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    CatenateLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DropoutLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], TotalLayer[], 
    TotalLayer[], DotPlusLayer[50], DotPlusLayer[1]}, {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3,
     1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 8, 
    6 -> 8, 7 -> 8, 8 -> 9, 10 -> 11, 10 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 
    12 -> 14, 11 -> 15, 13 -> 15, 13 -> 16, 12 -> 16, 16 -> 17, 
    15 -> 17, 14 -> 17, 17 -> 18, 18 -> 19, 9 -> 20, 20 -> 21, 
    19 -> 21, 21 -> 22, 23 -> 24, 23 -> 25, 23 -> 26, 24 -> 27, 
    25 -> 27, 24 -> 28, 25 -> 29, 26 -> 28, 26 -> 29, 27 -> 30, 
    28 -> 30, 29 -> 30, 30 -> 31, 31 -> 32, 32 -> 21, 30 -> 33, 
    8 -> 33, 8 -> 34, 17 -> 34, 30 -> 35, 17 -> 35, 33 -> 36, 
    34 -> 36, 34 -> 37, 35 -> 37, 37 -> 38, 36 -> 38, 38 -> 39, 
    39 -> 21, 22 -> 40}, "Input" -> 85]]
```

### NetPort

**From Sebastian**

> The inputs and outputs of layers and containers (like `NetGraph` and `NetChain`) are called "Ports". ``NetPort is a way to unambiguously refer to one of these inputs/outputs. For example, `MeanSquaredLossLayer` has two input ports, "Target" and "Input". Consider:

```
NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], DropoutLayer[], 
MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort[3, "Target"], 2 -> NetPort[3, "Input"]}]
```

`NetPort` allows you to specify exactly which input/output you are referring to.

It also lets you name your layers...
  NetGraph[{DotPlusLayer[5], SummationLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort["output"],2 -> NetPort["sum"]}]

Alternatively you can just do this directly in `NetChain`

```
simpleNet = NetChain[<|"Tanh" -> Tanh, "Dot" -> DotPlusLayer[7], "Sigmoid" -> LogisticSigmoid|>, "Input" -> 7];
```

## How to save your trained net

Very simple, use extension .wlnet

```
Export["file_of_your_net.wlnet",yourNet];
```

Important just requires this file...

## Graphs of basic elementwise layer functions

```
simpleNet = NetChain[{Ramp}];
ListLinePlot[simpleNet[Range[-5, 5]]]
simpleNet = NetChain[{Tanh}];
ListLinePlot[simpleNet[Range[-5, 5]]]
simpleNet = NetChain[{LogisticSigmoid}];
ListLinePlot[simpleNet[Range[-5, 5]]]
simpleNet = NetChain[{SoftmaxLayer[]}];
ListLinePlot[simpleNet[Range[-5, 5]]]
```

Comment: in `NetPort`,there is `NetGraph[{DotPlusLayer[5], SummationLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort["output"],2 -> NetPort["sum"]}]`.But it is not fully connected...

Answer (score 11):

Since `DeconvolutionLayer` did not receive much attention in the previous answers I'd like to present an application for it that maybe illustrates what it does.

Take for instance the following input data

```
data = {{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}};
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: data]

An up-sampling process can be implemented with `DeconvolutionLayer` as follows

```
upsampleLayer = 
DeconvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "Input" -> {1, 3, 3}, 
"Weights" -> {{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}}, 
"Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> {3, 3}]
```

Note the weight matrix `{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}` that has to be specified as a tensor of appropriate dimensions.

Applying the layer to the data yields

```
data // Apply[ArrayPlot[#, Mesh -> All] &]
```

[image: upsample1]

Note that the weight matrix used for up-sampling need not be the one specified. Try e.g. `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}` for a sparser up-sampling or `{{0.2, 0.2, 0.2}, {0.2, 1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2, 0.2}}` for a kind of anti-aliased up-sampling.

---

### Application of up-sampling with `DeconvolutionLayer`

A real world application for a construct like the one presented above is in Convolutional Auto-Encoders. I will present a minimal working example using MNIST

Training data

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
```

Adding a bit of noise to the images and building the training set / test set

```
 noisyTrainingsData = 
 trainingData // Part[#, All, 1] & // 
 Map[ImageAdd[#, Image@RandomReal[{0, 0.2}, {28, 28}]] -> # &]

 noisyTestData = 
 testData // Part[#, All, 1] & // 
 Map[ImageAdd[#, Image@RandomReal[{0, 0.2}, {28, 28}]] -> # &]
```

Defining network architecture

```
cae = NetChain[
{
ConvolutionLayer[10, {3, 3}],
ElementwiseLayer[Ramp],
PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}],
DeconvolutionLayer[10, {2, 2}, "Input" -> {10, 13, 13}, 
"Weights" -> Table[{{1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.2}}, 10, 10], 
"Biases" -> None, "Stride" -> {2, 2} ],
ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 2]
},
"Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}],
"Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", "Grayscale"}]
]
```

Training the network

```
trainedCAE = NetTrain[cae, noisyTrainingsData, 
Method -> "ADAM",BatchSize -> 30, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1]
```

Applying the trained CAE to some random image from the test set

```
With[{sample = RandomSample[noisyTestData, 1][[1, 1]]}, {sample, trainedCAE@sample}]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Concise example, I linked it in the O.P.

Answer (score 8):

## Useful User-defined functions

### Motivation

Perhaps I am alone in this, however I like to test my network against a variety of other methods, especially Random Forest. Yet, if you are using input with the `Head` `Dataset`, the functions `Predict` and `NetTrain` require different underlying structure. Notably, `Predict` is more friendly taking a standard data table layout that one may have in a csv, which can be nicely brought into Mathematica via `SematicImport.` So I am posting here a simple function that reformates your `Dataset` from the default imported layout (used for `Predict`) to a layout for `NetTrain`

### Example

#### Get data

```
pathToFile = "/User/file.csv";
D = SemanticImport[pathToFile];
```

#### Basic dataset for demonstration purposes

```
D = Dataset[
  <|
   "record1" -> <|"feature1" -> 1, "feature2" -> 2, 
     "feature3" -> 3, "toPredict" -> 4|>,
   "record2" -> <|"feature1" -> 1, "feature2" -> 2, "feature3" -> 3, 
     "toPredict" -> 4|>,
   "record3" -> <|"feature1" -> 1, "feature2" -> 2, "feature3" -> 3, 
     "toPredict" -> 4|>
   |>
  ]
```

### Supporting Functions

```
removeRowNames[dataset_] := Return[dataset[[Values]]]

unwrapAssociations[dataset_] := 
  If[MemberQ[dataset, _Association], 
   Return[Normal[dataset[[Values]]]], Return[dataset]];
```

### Reformat function

```
reformatForNetTrain[dataset_, output_] := Block[
  {data = dataset, outKey = output},

  columnNames = Normal[Keys@First@data];
  data = removeRowNames[data];

  out = data[[All, outKey]];
  inColumnNames = DeleteCases[columnNames, outKey];
  in = data[[All, inColumnNames]];

  out = unwrapAssociations[out];
  in = unwrapAssociations[in];

  newFormat = 
   Table[<|"Input" -> in[[i]], "Output" -> out[[i]]|>, {i, 1, 
     Length[in]}];
  Return[Dataset[newFormat]];
  ]
```

### Demo

```
D
reformatForNetTrain[D, "toPredict"]
```

### Output

[image]

[image]