# Neural Networks: Does Mathematica (v11) experimental code support state-of-art Models?

Tags: neural-networks

*Mathematica* made a big step implementing Neural Networks. I checked some examples for deep learning (ChainNet), also the related [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124977/qa-mathematica-v-11-neural-networks-a-comprehensive-look-at-layers-net-functi). I see that model structures such as LaNet can be developed. Before I go further with NN, I was wondering:

1. If the current ChainNet supports state of art structures such as
   Imagenet, Inception V3, Xception (newer version of Inception) and
   ResNet, etc.?
2. Are there any other model structures available in *Mathematica*?

Comment: v11.0.1 doesn't support recurrent or recursive neurons, so don't expect to get resnet or lstms working, but they did announce they are working on a website with a gallery of nets for next release in the spring

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mathematica's neural network functionality is based on [MXNET](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet). So you can use pre-trained models for MXNET or create and train state-of-the-art models with `NetGraph`.

For example, pre-trained Inception-V3:

https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet-model-gallery/blob/master/imagenet-1k-inception-v3.md

```
URLDownload[
  "http://data.dmlc.ml/mxnet/models/imagenet/inception-v3.tar.gz",
  FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "inception-v3.tar.gz"}]
  ];

ExtractArchive["inception-v3.tar.gz"];

Needs["NeuralNetworks`"]

net = NeuralNetworks`ImportMXNetModel[
  "model//Inception-7-symbol.json",
  "model//Inception-7-0001.params"
  ]
```

[image]

Newest '[Xception](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/xception.py)'-model is not replicable right now. Because MXNET doesn't have [SeparableConv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#separableconvolution2d) and [GlobalAveragePooling2D](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalaveragepooling2d) layers. Even in the Keras SeparableConv2D layer is available only with the TensorFlow backend. Global(Average|Max)Pooling exists in MXNET but not realized in Mathematica.

**UPDATE**

Since the V11.1 we can use `AggregationLayer` for global pooling.

SeparableConv2D can be built from the other layers.

```
n = 128; h = 3; w = 3; depth = 2;

NetChain[
 {
  ReplicateLayer[1],
  TransposeLayer[],
  NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[depth, {h, w}]],
  FlattenLayer[1],
  ConvolutionLayer[n, {1, 1}]
  },
 "Input" -> {32, 9, 9}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Will you add the option 'global_pool' for the PoolingLayer? [mxnet source code](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/src/operator/pooling-inl.h)

Comment: Thank you very much for this informative answer!

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev You can use `AggregationLayer` for global pooling

Comment: @Sascha Yes, I've seen. I've updated my answer. Now we have all ingredients for Xception. When I have time, I'll try to replicate it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore - `FlattenLayer` gives this error: `Type inconsistency in FlattenLayer: dynamic dimensions cannot be flattened with other levels.`

Comment: @CarlLange Yes, I know. I have reported this bug to the developers a few months ago.

Comment: Hopefully fixed for 12, will report back when it's out.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, the issue with FlattenLayer is solved when you specify "Input" for that layer, eg: `FlattenLayer[1, "Input" -> {32, 2, 7, 7}]`.

Answer (score 22):

Bring in pre-trained models is sometimes very useful. Alexey's answer is somewhat brief, here I'm trying to add some examples hopefully will be helpful.

We can load the trained network by

```
net = NeuralNetworks`ImportMXNetModel[
  "model/Inception-7-symbol.json",
  "model/Inception-7-0001.params"
  ]
```

and attach the final softmax layer to calculate the probabilities in each class:

```
net2 = NetGraph[{net, SoftmaxLayer[]}, {1 -> 2}, 
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}], 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[1008]}]]
```

The prediction label/text mapping is in the file synset.txt:

```
labels = Import["model/synset.txt", "Table"]
```

We can then use the inception network to identify images. For example

```
imgs = EntityValue[#, "Image"] & /@ {Entity["Species", 
    "Infraspecies:CanisLupusFamiliaris"], 
   Entity["Species", "Species:FelisCatus"], 
   Entity["Species", "Species:PantheraTigris"], 
   Entity["Species", "Genus:Macropus"]}
```

[image]

and the labels are identified fairly accurately

```
labels[[net2[ImageResize[#, {299, 299}]]]] & /@ imgs
(* {{"n02099601", "golden", "retriever"}, 
    {"n02127052", "lynx,", "catamount"},
    {"n02129604", "tiger,", "Panthera", "tigris"},
    {"n01877812", "wallaby,", "brush", "kangaroo"}} *)
```

We can also try to visualize the weights in its layers. For example, here are the weights the one channel of the first convolution layer:

```
weight = NetExtract[net, {1, "Weights"}];
ImageCollage[
 Table[ImageAdjust[
   Image[weight[[n, All, All]], ColorSpace -> "RGB"]], {n, 1, 32}], 
 ImagePadding -> 1]
```

[image]

And we can see what these convolution filters do to the input image:

```
conv = NetChain[{NetExtract[net, 1]}, 
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]];
data = conv@ImageResize[#, {299, 299}] &@imgs[[1]];
ImageCollage[ImageAdjust@Image[#] & /@ data]
```

[image]

We can also use `Take` to cut the inception model at some layer, and visualize the propagated input image at that layer:

```
layers = Take[net, {"conv_conv2d", "mixed_2_tower_1_conv_1_conv2d"}]
```

[image]

```
NetChain[{layers}, 
 "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]]
data2 = net3@ImageResize[#, {299, 299}] &@imgs[[1]];
ImageCollage[ImageAdjust@Image[#] & /@ data2, ImagePadding -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanations and examples. Also, related for the records :) ... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131615/neural-networks-modifiying-nn-structures

Answer (score 8):

**XCEPTION**

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02357
[image]

```
entry = NetGraph[
  <|
   "conv_1" -> ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}, "Stride" -> 2],
   "relu_1" -> Ramp,

   "conv_2" -> ConvolutionLayer[64, {3, 3}],
   "relu_2" -> Ramp,

   "resid_1" -> ConvolutionLayer[128, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 2],

   "sep_conv_1" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[128, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_3" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_2" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[128, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "max_pool_1" -> 
    PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 1],

   "add_1" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus],

   "resid_2" -> ConvolutionLayer[256, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 2],

   "relu_4" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_3" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[256, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_5" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_4" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[256, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "max_pool_2" -> 
    PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 1],

   "add_2" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus],

   "resid_3" -> ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 2],

   "relu_6" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_5" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_7" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_6" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "max_pool_3" -> 
    PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 1],

   "add_3" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus]
   |>
  ,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> 
    "conv_1" -> 
     "relu_1" -> "conv_2" -> "relu_2" -> "resid_1" -> "add_1",
   "relu_2" -> 
    "sep_conv_1" -> 
     "relu_3" -> "sep_conv_2" -> "max_pool_1" -> "add_1",
   "add_1" -> "resid_2" -> "add_2",
   "add_1" -> 
    "relu_4" -> 
     "sep_conv_3" -> 
      "relu_5" -> "sep_conv_4" -> "max_pool_2" -> "add_2",
   "add_2" -> "resid_3" -> "add_3",
   "add_2" -> 
    "relu_6" -> 
     "sep_conv_5" -> 
      "relu_7" -> "sep_conv_6" -> "max_pool_3" -> "add_3"
   }
  ,
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
middle = NetGraph[
  <|
   "relu_1" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_1" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_2" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_2" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_3" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_3" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "add" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus]
   |>
  ,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> 
    "relu_1" -> 
     "sep_conv_1" -> 
      "relu_2" -> "sep_conv_2" -> "relu_3" -> "sep_conv_3" -> "add",
   NetPort["Input"] -> "add"
   }
  ,
  "Input" -> {728, 19, 19}
  ]
```

[image]

```
exit = NetGraph[
  <|
   "resid" -> ConvolutionLayer[1024, {1, 1}, "Stride" -> 2],

   "relu_1" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_1" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[728, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "relu_2" -> Ramp,
   "sep_conv_2" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[1024, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],

   "max_pool" -> 
    PoolingLayer[{3, 3}, "Stride" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 1],

   "add" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus],

   "sep_conv_3" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[1536, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],
   "relu_3" -> Ramp,

   "sep_conv_4" ->
    NetGraph[
     {
      ReplicateLayer[1],
      TransposeLayer[],
      NetMapOperator[ConvolutionLayer[1, {3, 3}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]],
      FlattenLayer[1],
      ConvolutionLayer[2048, {1, 1}]
      },
     {1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5}
     ],
   "relu_4" -> Ramp,

   "global_pool" -> AggregationLayer[Mean],

   "softmax" -> {2048, SoftmaxLayer[]} 
   |>
  ,
  {
   NetPort["Input"] -> "resid" -> "add",
   NetPort["Input"] -> 
    "relu_1" -> 
     "sep_conv_1" -> "relu_2" -> "sep_conv_2" -> "max_pool" -> "add",
   "add" -> 
    "sep_conv_3" -> 
     "relu_3" -> "sep_conv_4" -> "relu_4" -> "global_pool" -> "softmax"
   }
  ,
  "Input" -> {728, 19, 19}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[2048]}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
xception = NetChain[
  <|
   "entry_flow" -> entry,
   "middle_flow" -> NetNestOperator[middle, 8],
   "exit_flow" -> exit
   |>
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for provide so powerful method to construct a b network！

Answer (score 2):

After Alexey Golyshev's nice answer I sow some other models that those could be found from the same site http://data.dmlc.ml/mxnet/models/ but I'm not sure if they are compatible with version 11.  In addition, one can download inception v3 from an other source explaining deep learning tutorial from *Wolfram* https://www.wolfram.com/events/cvpr-2016-tutorials/ and model from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jeh98c7dqk58s9o/AABm9L3HwQn6sz0sQPHoCIbna?dl=0 .