# Neural Networks: Modifiying NN structures?

Tags: neural-networks

From this nice [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129469/neural-networks-does-mathematica-v11-experimental-code-support-state-of-art-m) one can import pretrained NN models and structures for state of art models.

```
URLDownload[
  "http://data.dmlc.ml/mxnet/models/imagenet/inception-v3.tar.gz",
   FileNameJoin[{$UserDocumentsDirectory, "inception-v3.tar.gz"}]
];

ExtractArchive["inception-v3.tar.gz"];
Needs["NeuralNetworks`"]

net = NeuralNetworks`ImportMXNetModel[
 "model//Inception-7-symbol.json",
 "model//Inception-7-0001.params"
]
```

The returned result is NetGraph object. In this object, imported models uses NetPort for inputs, as a result one must enter tensor with given dimensions. However, *Mathematica* has some nice encoders:

```
enc = NetEncoder[{"Image", {150, 150}}]
```

**My question:**

Is it possible to change ports inputting tensors to these *Mathematica* defined encoders? If so, how?

**Upadate:**

In addition, I would like to know if it's possible in the inception model to change the number of output classes. Currently, I want to use the structure but not pretrained model with 1008 classes. Lets say I want 10 new classes for output. How can I modify DotPlusLayer("fc1"), SoftMaxLayer("softmax") and Port "Output" for this 10 classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
net = NeuralNetworks`ImportMXNetModel[
  "model//Inception-7-symbol.json",
  "model//Inception-7-0001.params"
  ]
```

This network accepts images in resolution 299x299.

```
SeedRandom[1];
img = RandomImage[1, {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"];

net2 = NetGraph[
  {
   net,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  {1 -> 2},
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}],
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[1008]}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
net2[img]
```

> 920

**UPDATE**

If we want to keep neural architecture but change the number of classes (for example, add 10 new), we can trim original architecture using `Take`.

```
net3 = NetGraph[
  {
   Take[net, {NetPort["Input"], "flatten"}],
   1008 + 10,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  {1 -> 2 -> 3},
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {299, 299}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}], 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[1008 + 10]}]
  ]
```

[image]

But this network should be trained again, because it doesn't keep information about previously learned classes.

```
NetExtract[net3, {2, "Weights"}]
```

> Automatic

Comment: Ohh, thank you! I thought I should overwrite the ports! Nice solution.

Comment: @s.s.o  I am glad to help you. Look at the image. This is a network inside the network.

Comment: It was helpful thank you very much. I would like to know if it's possible in the inception model to change the number of output classes. Currently, I want to use the structure but not pretrained model with 1008 classes. Lets say I want 10 new classes for output. How can I modify DotPlusLayer("fc1"), SoftMaxLayer("softmax") and Port "Output" for this 10 classes. If it's possible I'll edit the question with new parts, too.

Comment: @s.s.o See update.