# Has the usage of CrossEntropyLossLayer changed?

Tags: neural-networks

Reading [this answer about `CrossEntropyLossLayer`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124977/qa-mathematica-v-11-neural-networks-a-comprehensive-look-at-layers-net-functi/124995#124995), I find the following.

---

[image]

---

But when I evaluate the same code, I get errors.

```
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {1}, "Target" -> 1|>]
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {2}, "Target" -> 1|>]
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {20}, "Target" -> 1|>]
CrossEntropyLossLayer[][<|"Input" -> {200}, "Target" -> 1|>]
```

[image]

So has the usage of `CrossEntropyLossLayer` changed?

I am using Version 11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)

Comment: The Wolfram documentation article for `CrossEntropyLossLayer` clearly states that there were changes made in V11.1.0