# Upsampling layer for convolutional autoencoder

Tags: neural-networks

I've been trying to build a convolutional autoencoder with Mathematica 12.3. For this, I need to reverse the action of `PoolingLayer[]`. Is there any layer similar to Keras's [`UpSampling1D`](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/up_sampling1d/)? Could, perhaps, `ReplicateLayer[]` be handy here?

I just found [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124977/qa-mathematica-v-11-neural-networks-a-comprehensive-look-at-layers-net-functi/139138#139138) that talks about implementing an upsampling operation with `DeconvolutionLayer[]`.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, UpSampling1D is equivalent to:

```
upsampling1DLayer[size_] := 
 NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[size, -2], 
   TransposeLayer[{-2 <-> -1, -3 <-> -2}], FlattenLayer[-1], 
   TransposeLayer[{-2 <-> -1}]}]
```

Applying to the example shown in Keras' documentation:

```
di = {{{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11}}}
upsampling1DLayer[2]@di
```

> {{{0., 1., 2.}, {0., 1., 2.}, {3., 4., 5.}, {3., 4., 5.}}, {{6., 7.,
> 8.}, {6., 7., 8.}, {9., 10., 11.}, {9., 10., 11.}}}